# Rails isn't loading my JS properly - ERROR bad Request-Line `'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.2.3 app isn't consistently loading JS files. I just started working on the JS, so I'm not sure if this just started, or if it's been this way since I started it a few days ago.

The two other guys working on the project are not having any problems at all. But sometimes it loads all of my files, sometimes it skips some, there doesn't seem to be any pattern.

Sometimes it loads app.js, sometimes it doesn't. Same thing with the other js files.

I'm seeing the following show up multiple times in my rails log:

ERROR bad Request-Line `'.

I'm at a loss here...

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require util
//= require app
//= require_tree .
```

Here is what the log file is showing:

```
Started GET "/assets/user_manager.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-07 18:02:13 -0500
Served asset /user_manager.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/util.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-07 18:02:13 -0500
Served asset /util.js - 200 OK (0ms)
[2012-11-07 18:02:13] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.
[2012-11-07 18:02:13] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.
[2012-11-07 18:02:13] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.


Started GET "/assets/header/topnav/separator.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-07 18:02:13 -0500
Served asset /header/topnav/separator.png - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/header/pagetitle-bg.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-07 18:02:13 -0500
Served asset /header/pagetitle-bg.png - 200 OK (0ms)
[2012-11-07 18:02:13] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.


Started GET "/assets/header_bg.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-07 18:02:13 -0500
Served asset /header_bg.png - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/header_bg.png"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/c[2012-11-07 18:02:13] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.
ontent_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/rob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/rob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/rob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in     start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@admin/gems/actionpack-3.2.    3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/background/header_blueprint.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-07 18:02:13 -0500
Served asset /background/header_blueprint.png - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-07 18:02:13 -0500
Served asset /images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/rob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/rob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/rob/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in     start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@admin/gems/actionpack-3.2.    3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
[2012-11-07 18:02:13] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.
[2012-11-07 18:02:13] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.
[2012-11-07 18:02:13] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.
```

Comment: You might consider adding some code snippets for people to get an idea what you're doing. It's extremely difficult to help debug this kind of issue without seeing the code you're using.

Comment: What browser are you using? It might be caching old js files, you can try clearing your cache or switching to incognito mode if using chrome. Conversely, your co-workers might have older files cached that your application is no longer serving.

Comment: Are you all on the same OS, using the same line endings, and working in UTF-8?  Might want to post some more of your logs.

Comment: I just tried another Rails app and it is having the same problem. I tried it in Safari and Canary, neither of which are showing any problems. So, it seems like it's a Chrome issue? Chrome v23.0.1271.64, Mac OSX v10.7.4

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with JS and CSS files randomly failing to load in Google Chrome, this error showing in the logs:

```
ERROR bad Request-Line `'.
```

The problem must have been cookie related, though deleting the cookie did not work for me. I solved the problem by renaming they key in `config/initializers/session_store.rb` and then renaming it back once the problem was gone. Strange.